# How can I complete a form JSP action before executing the onsubmit Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a form in "index.jsp" which is used to upload images:

```
<div id="uploadsContainer" class="mm11Container" style="top:100px; left: 300px;">
            <div id="mydiv" class="mm11 card front face">
                <form id= "uploadForm" action="imageUploadForm.jsp" onsubmit="setUploadedBackground('<%=fileName%>', '<%=uploadResult%>');" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input class="uploads" type="file" name="file" size="50"/>
                    <input class="uploadFile" id='submitImage' type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The code in "imageUploadForm.jsp" will check that the file uploaded is actually an image and doesn't exceed the maximum file size and returns a result code to "index.jsp" as well as storing the name of the file uploaded (assuming it uploaded correctly) in a database.

What I want is that right after this has happened, the JS function

```
setUploadedBackground('<%=fileName%>', '<%=uploadResult%>');
```

is called - this will use the result code to either alert that the max file size has been exceeded, alert the user that the uploaded file is not an image, or actually set the background of "mydiv" to the uploaded image. I want this to happen as soon as the Upload button is clicked and the action page has finished running and returned a result code. The JS uses Ajax to do this without another page reload:

```
function setUploadedBackground(fileName, uploadResult){
    alert("Function called uploadResult = "+uploadResult+ " fileName = "+ fileName);
    if (uploadResult === "0" && fileName != null) {
        alert("Uploading image");
        var ajx;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// If the browser if IE7+[or] Firefox[or] Chrome[or] Opera[or]Safari
            ajx=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {//If browser is IE6, IE5
            ajx=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        ajx.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (ajx.readyState==4 && ajx.status==200)
            {
                alert("Here");
                $("#mydiv").css('background-image', 'url(uploads/'+fileName+')');
                $("#mydiv").css('background-size', '100%');
            }
        }
        ajx.open("GET","index.jsp",true);
        ajx.send();
        return false;
    }
    else if (uploadResult.equals("1")) {
        alert("Maximum file size exceeded");
    } else if (uploadResult.equals("2")) {
        alert("Please upload an image");
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have been searching for ages but am not sure how to get the action JSP to execute first, before the JS, without having to add yet another button which would be called 'Set as abackground' and could be used after the image has been uploaded...any help is much appreciated!

Comment: See this link http://fineuploader.com/demos#various-options

Comment: not sure how helpful that it, I've looked at some of their code but don't think all of it is available..I feel I must be missing something..surely I don't need yet another button, I can have an action followed by a JS function?

Comment: I think you are mixing two different concepts. in your form, you will choose a file to upload and the click on "upload file" button. what happens next, depends on your code. 1- you can choose to upload the image via `ajax` and do the validation and then store the image on the server and return the image `url` to the client to show it in ""#mydiv", or 2- the form will be posted normally and the page will refresh and same thing happens after the page refresh. if you want to prevent the page refresh, then you have to choose ajax so the link @NullPointerException provided will do the trick for you